# Centering text vertically within a display:table-cell div that also has vertical-align:top content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm using display:table and display:table-cell to display a div as if it were a table. I want the contents of one div (.cellcontents) to be vertically centered as if it were in a table cell, the problem is that I have another div (.cellhead) with the same parent that I want to have vertically aligned to the top.

So what I want is something like this

```
|     |length|
|     |      |
|[img]| 120m |
|     |      |
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Am I going about this the wrong way entirely? Current html:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="film row">
    <div class="poster cell">[IMG]</div>
    <div class="detail cell last">
      <div class="cellhead">length</div>
      <div class="cellcontents">120 minutes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css is here

```
.table {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: none;
}
.film .cell.poster {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 140px;
  height: 5em;
}
.film .cell.detail {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
.film .cell div.cellhead {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.film .cell.last {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting tabular data in divs?

Comment: Not the best solution buy maybe you could use `position: absolute` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/964/

Comment: Because I it makes changing the display easier with a media screen for width later on.

Comment: @pg. Ok that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, but it requires different markup.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.table .table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.row, .cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    height: 5em;
}
.cell .cell {
    border: none;
}
.row.head {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.cell.detail {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
.cell.poster {
    height: 5em;
    width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell poster">[IMG]</div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="row head">length</div>
            <div class="cell detail">120 minutes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Setting `.cell.detail` height to 100% allows it to take up the most space.

Comment: thanks! this will work. I knew it was something like nesting tables. CHanging the markup is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

See the differences [here](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=4anly)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: none;
}
.film .cell.poster {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 140px;
  height: 5em;
}
.film .cell.detail {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
.film .cell div.cellhead {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  height: 20%;
}
.film .cell.last {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.film .cell.last .cellcontents{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="film row">
    <div class="poster cell">[IMG]</div>
    <div class="detail cell last">
      <div class="cellhead">length</div>
      <div class="cellcontents">120 minutes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simplified version with an absolute positioned div.

Hope it helps.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: none;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.table, .cell {
  height: 5em;
}

.cell:first-child {
  width: 140px;
}

.cell:last-child {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 200px;
}

.cell > div.heading {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    [IMG]
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    120 minutes
    <div class="heading">length</div>
  </div>
</div>
```